# Bug: Mule xpath3 transform gets transformed namespaces wrong in edge-case

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

When XML which contains the XMLSchema namespace

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

but *only* utilised within an XMLSchema-instance

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

such as:

```
<nsp:Value xsi:type="xs:int">1</nsp:Value>
```

is transformed using xpath3 such as:

```
#[xpath3('//nsp:Configuration', message.payload, 'NODESET')]
```

then the XMLSchema namespace definition will not be added to the outgoing XML. All other namespace definitions will be added fine, but because the xs namespace is only utilised within an attribute value, it appears to not be correctly added.

I would also add that I have added a mulexml:namespace-manager containing these namespaces as well as my custom ones, but that it seems to make no difference.

Does anyone know where should I report this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can report this in the project jira

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/login.jsp

Also if you are a enterprise customer you should report it via your customer portal.